# How to create a flag for duplicate values in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i would like to know how to create a flag for duplicate rows in a table.for example : if i get duplicate rows it will show me 1 and if i dont get any duplicate rows,it will display 0

i tried the following for this test table i have used to check whether or not it will work

```
SQL> select * from t_flag
  2  /

EMP_NAME                   EMP_NO DEPT
-------------------------------------------------- --------- --------------------

    ROBI                        1 AGRO
    ROBI                        1 AGRO
    BORIS                       2 IT
    SID                         3 VET
    BORIS                       2 IT

    select t_flag.*,
 (case when row_number() over (partition by emp_name,emp_no,dept order by emp_name) = 1
                 then 0 else 1
            end) as GroupFlag
 from t_flag
SQL> /

EMP_NAME                                              EMP_NO DEPT                 GROUPFLAG
-------------------------------------------------- --------- -------------------- ---------
BORIS                                                      2 IT                           0
BORIS                                                      2 IT                           1
ROBI                                                       1 AGRO                         0
ROBI                                                       1 AGRO                         1
SID                                                        3 VET                          0
```

what i would like to get from the result is : 1 for duplicate rows 
and 0 for non-duplicate rows

thanks!

Comment: Use `COUNT()` analytic function instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: The question is: why do you allow duplicates?

Comment: @jarlh,i get duplicate rows often times in my oracle tables at work.thats why i have to check the tables before proceeding for updates,insertions etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use analytic functions with `case`.  But the one you want is `count(*)` rather than `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by emp_name, emp_no, dept) > 1
             then 1 else 0
        end) as groupflag
from t_flag t;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply with the new query.it would be best if i could do the checking with all the tables using this query.

Comment: The question you asked is about a single table.  If you have a question about multiple tables, then please ask *another* question.  I find it impolite when OPs change their questions and invalidate answers, because the answers then might draw downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

### you can also do it in this way. hope it helps:)

```
select 
    case when count >1 
        then 'D' 
        else 'U' end as GroupFlag, 
    emp_name, 
    emp_no, 
    dept from (
       select emp_name, emp_no, dept, count(*) as count 
           from t_flag 
              group by emp_name, emp_no, dept
    );
```